# Regex get last occurrence of a pattern with negative sign

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I've been following [Freecodecamp's tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/simple-regex-tricks-for-beginners-3acb3fa257cb/) on Regex to be able to get the last occurrence of the pattern I intend to get. I intend to get the number (with / without a negative sign), the number, and **any character** that comes after that.

**Goal:**

```
    aa-11aa -> gets the -11aa
    11aa -> gets the 11aa
    aa11aa11aa -> gets the 2nd 11aa
    aa-11aa-11aa -> gets the 2nd -11aa
    aa-11a(a) -> gets the -11a(a)
```

However, I've only gotten this pattern to work to only get a single digit and the post fix of whatever comes after the number. `(?:.*)(-*\d+)(.*)$`. These are the results from my pattern:

**Issue:**

```
    aa-11aa -> gets the 1aa
    11aa -> gets the 1aa
    aa11aa11aa -> get the 2nd 1aa
    aa-11aa-11aa -> get the 2nd 1aa
    aa-11a(a) -> gets the 1a(a)
```

Any help on how I can get my desired result?

Comment: How about (?:.*?)(-*\d+)(.*)$. Making the first group nongreedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
.*?(-?\d+[^\d]*)$
```

First non-greedily match any preceding characters, then in your group conditionally match the minus sign followed by some numbers followed by zero or more characters that are not a number

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-?\d+[^\d]+$
```

It was including the second occurrence of the digits too, as `.` means any character.

Note that,
`\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

Comment: It's a good attempt; however, it isn't able to get **any** character after the number. I wasn't able to add an example where a string can be `aa-11a(a)`.

Comment: You wanted **any character** after the number? Modified the answer.

Comment: it's currently matching all occurrences. I only intend to get the last one

Comment: Updated. This should do.

Comment: yup. that works too. thanks!